# What causes headaches after using the sauna?

Tags: post-workout

I sometimes enjoy sitting in the sauna after my workout. But it seems whenever I do, I get a headache later in the evening. I use the sauna in the evening. I think I'm drinking enough water but maybe not? What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no expert, but lack of hydration is usually the reason given for headaches after sauna.  Here are some points to consider:

- Avoid alcohol and caffeine before and after a sauna.
- Drink water before, after and maybe even during a sauna.
- Replenish electrolytes. When you re-hydrate remember that it isn't just water that is lost but electrolytes also. Recommendations that I found include coconut water, fruit or fruit juice, sea salt and regular vitamin/mineral supplements to help replenish your electrolytes like sodium, potassium, calcium and magnesium.

Try any of those to see if it makes a difference. Build up slowly and cool off with a cool shower afterwards. If those don't make a difference, check with your doctor. Heat can be a trigger for some people who have migraines.  Also it may not just be a factor of the heat and hydration, it may be the type of sauna that is affecting you. Check on the type of sauna you are using - "wet vs dry", or "conventional vs infrared".

Comment: I have used the sauna a few times now, and by drinking copious amounts of water (1.8L in 30 minutes) while in the sauna, I have not had another headache.

Comment: Good to hear.  I noticed leg cramps after I started using a sauna regularly and they went away when I hydrated better.  I guess there is something to it!

Answer (score 1):

Serious banya (sauna) users in Russia wear skull caps to prevent dilation of the blood vessels in the head and thereby preventing post banya headache Also do not forget the cold dip after the banya.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that the mechanism has do do with inflammation related to too much prolonged stretching of of brain blood vessel walls? I would say to continue to stay hydrated and try to get a sense of when to get out of the sauna before a headache is induced?

Answer (score 0):

I am convinced that it is from alcohol and caffine. Of course  the sauna experience is a lot better with lots of hydration, but they can still occur. I am sipping a mango drink and praying that it goes away. Diblerately wearing a dampened skull cap too. I feel your pain.. it is a 1st world problem. Cover your head with a cloth before you sleep and sip water, the only effective cure I know. Happy days